# How to test if certain event is supported?

Tags: vimscript, neovim

I want to test in a script if this version of vim supports the "CmdlineEnter" event.

This is a relatively new addition in vim and neovim doesn't support it in it's current 0.2.2 version (although there is a merged PR that adds that event)

How can I test if this event is supported in the current version of vim?

```
  has(CmdlineEnter)
```

raises an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are at least three ways to tell if a particular autocmd is supported:

1. Use `exists('##CmdlineEnter')`. This should be exactly what you need.
2. Check for the patch it was introduced in.  For example, `CmdlineEnter` was added in patch [8.0.1206](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/fafcf0dd59fd9c4ef743bb333ae40d1d322b6079).  I determined this by looking at recent vim commits and git blame on the help files.  Thus you can use `has('patch-8.0.1206')`.  Although Neovim does not follow vim development exactly, when features are added from "upstream," the vim patch numbers are included too.
3. Use a `try|catch|endtry` block around `autocmd`.  E.g.,

```
try
     silent autocmd CmdlineEnter
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E216/
     " autocmd is not supported
endtry
```

When installing an autocmd handler you could simply use `silent! autocmd CmdlineEnter * ...` to suppress all errors, if your code doesn't actually need to know whether the command is supported.

Alternatively, you can check if an autocmd is *subscribed to* using `exists('#CmdlineEnter')`.  This will return 0 if the autocmd exists but has no listeners.  Sometimes this is all the info you need.

Comment: You can use `exists('##CmdlineEnter')`

Comment: Ahh, yeah... that's the correct answer

Comment: \@Mass, @Christian Brabandt Thank you both. Exactly what I needed

Comment: What does **##** mean?

Comment: Hey @JonathanWheeler!  In `exists('##CmdlineEnter')`  `##` is essentially a signifier/sigil for "autocmd event."  Kind of like saying `event_exists('CmdlineEnter')`.  Meaning it's a real supported event in vim.

Comment: Could someone provide a link to the document about `##`? It seems it doesn't exist in the vim `autocmd.txt` help document.

Comment: @SanghyunLee it is in `eval.txt` , `:h exists`;  ` ##event  autocommand for this event is supported.`

Comment: Great, thanks, @Mass!